# Sum of $n$ terms of the series $\frac 1{(1 + x)(1 +2x)} + \frac 1{(1 +2x)(1 +3x)} + \ldots$ is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My try : By using Vn Method 
[image]

But the answer is $\frac n{(1+x)(1+ (n+1)x)}$
Please tell me where I am wrong or what is the correct method to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Please rotate photograph.

Comment: The general term should be $\frac{1}{(1+nx)[1+(n+1)x]}$ instead of $\frac{1}{(1+nx)(1+2nx)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am sorry but, being almost blind, I am unable to read your photograph.*

Considering $$a_n=\frac n{(1+x)(1+ (n+1)x)}$$ use patrial fraction decomposition to get
$$a_n=\frac{n+1}{(n+1) x+1}-\frac{n}{n x+1}$$ which beautifully telescopes.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Yeah , thanks understood the concept , sorry for the bad picture

Comment: @user580093. You are welcome ! On this site, if I may suggest, use MathJax for typing; it is quite easy and you will probably get more answers than when posting photographs. Cheers.